# I want a part of the_content be under custom post types

Tags: the-content

On my homepage I have put some information on the page in wordpress. I show this content with `the_content();`. I also have 3 different custom post types that show under this content which is what I want. But now I need to have a part of the content that comes from the page in wordpress to be under these custom post types. I made a image to clear things ups. How do I do this without removing "THIS" from the homepage page in wordpress [image]

Comment: What have you tried so far. Please add some code that is relevant to what you have done thus far, working or not.

Comment: How are your three red "content" blocks differentiated?

Answer (score 0):

The path of least resistance is to simply add a custom field to this page and plug in your second chunk of content in that. Then call this field where ever you would like. I use the advanced custom field plug in. But there are many options out there.